# Count percentage of days left

Tags: javascript, html, date

I made this script but it shows that 99% is done idk why

code:

```
function Percentage(){ 
            var start = new Date(2021,3,16),
            end = new Date(2021,6,8),
            today = new Date();
            progress =  100 - (((end - start) * 100 ) / today)
            alert((progress).toFixed(11) + '%')

            setTimeout("Percentage()",10)
}
```

Comment: What are `start`, `end` and `today` good for, when they don’t get used anywhere? And what is `progress` supposed to be? Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue.

Comment: sorry it havent pasted idk why

Comment: The formula is wrong.  I think `end` and `today` are swapped.

Comment: Your formula there does not appear to make much sense. I think you want to get the percentage “relation” between the full time interval from start to end, and the interval from start to today? If your interval was 100 days long, and today was the tenth day from the start, then you want 10% as result? Then you need to subtract start _from_ today as well.

Comment: When you divide `(end - start) / today`, the numerator is a duration while the denominator is a date. Maybe `(end - start) / (today - start)`, as CBroe said?

Comment: i tried that too but it doest work still 99.999999995

Comment: Did you try `progress =  100 - (((end - start) * 100 ) / (today - start))` ? The parentheses matter so that the order of operations is correct...

Comment: `end - start` is the full interval, `today - start` is the time that has already passed. So if you want to know how many percent _of_ the former, the latter represents - then you need to divide `today - start` _by_ `end - start`, and multiple the result with 100.

Comment: whoops, yeah, the numerator/denominator are swapped.

Comment: when u will do progress =  100 - (((end - start) * 100 ) / (today - start)) it will show 375%

Comment: The start date is 16th April 2021. Javascript month starts with 0. For better understanding, try printing start and end dates on console.

Comment: even it is  it doesnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

As I said, Javascript month starts with 0.
Set the start and end dates accordingly
Also, if progress percentage means number of days passed out of total available days then

```
        progress =  (((today-start) * 100 ) / (end-start))
```

If progress percentage means number of days left out of total days available then it should be

```
        progress =  100 - (((today-start) * 100 ) / (end-start))
```

Comment: You don't need so many brackets: `100 - (today-start) * 100  / (end - start)`. ;-)